# Using list elements and indices together

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, indices

I've always found it awkward to have a function or expression that requires use of the values, as well as indices, of a list (or array, applies just the same) in Haskell.

I wrote `validQueens` below while experimenting with the N-queens problem  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470412/extent-of-ghcs-optimization) ...

```
validQueens x = 
     and [abs (x!!i - x!!j) /= j-i | i<-[0..length x - 2], j<-[i+1..length x - 1]]
```

I didn't care for the use of indexing, all the plus and minuses, etc.  It feels sloppy.  I came up with the following:

```
enumerate x = zip [0..length x - 1] x

validQueens' :: [Int] -> Bool
validQueens' x = and [abs (snd j - snd i) /= fst j - fst i | i<-l, j<-l, fst j > fst i]
                   where l = enumerate x
```

being inspired by Python's `enumerate` (not that borrowing imperative concepts is necessarily a great idea).  Seems better in concept, but `snd` and `fst` all over the place kinda sucks.  It's also, at least at first glance, costlier both in time and space.  I'm not sure whether or not I like it any better.

So in short, I am not really satisfied with either

1. Iterating thru by index bounded by lengths, or even worse, off-by-ones and twos
2. Index-element tuples

Has anyone found a pattern they find more elegant than either of the above?  If not, is there any compelling reason one of the above methods is superior?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Borrowing `enumerate` is fine and encouraged. However, it can be made a bit lazier by refusing to calculate the length of its argument:

```
enumerate = zip [0..]
```

(In fact, it's common to just use `zip [0..]` without naming it `enumerate`.) It's not clear to me why you think your second example should be costlier in either time or space. Remember: indexing is O(n), where n is the index. Your complaint about the unwieldiness of `fst` and `snd` is justified, and can be remedied with pattern-matching:

```
validQueens' xs = and [abs (y - x) /= j - i | (i, x) <- l, (j, y) <- l, i < j]
    where l = zip [0..] xs
```

Now, you might be a bit concerned about the efficiency of this double loop, since the clause `(j, y) <- l` is going to be running down the entire spine of `l`, when really we just want it to start where we left off with `(i, x) <- l`. So, let's write a function that implements that idea:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs xs = [(x, y) | x:ys <- tails xs, y <- ys]
```

Having made this function, your function is not too hard to adapt. Pulling out the predicate into its own function, we can use `all` instead of `and`:

```
validSingleQueen ((i, x), (j, y)) = abs (y - x) /= j - i
validQueens' xs = all validSingleQueen (pairs (zip [0..] xs))
```

Or, if you prefer point-free notation:

```
validQueens' = all validSingleQueen . pairs . zip [0..]
```

Answer (score 20):

Index-element tuples are quite a common thing to do in Haskell. Because `zip` stops when the first list stops, you can write them as

```
enumerate x = zip [0..] x
```

which is both more elegant and more efficient (as it doesn't compute `length x` up front). In fact I wouldn't even bother naming it, as `zip [0..]` is so short.

This is definitely more efficient than iterating by index for lists, because `!!` is linear in the second argument due to lists being linked lists.

Another way you can make your program more elegant is to use pattern-matching instead of `fst` and `snd`:

```
validQueens' :: [Int] -> Bool
validQueens' x = and [abs (j2 - i2) /= j1 - i1 | (i1, i2) <-l, (j1, j2) <-l, j1 > i1]
                   where l = zip [0..] x
```