# Managing state in a Minesweeper clone in Haskell

Tags: haskell

As a way to learn Haskell I decided to make a Minesweeper clone. I have already written some code and the main structure of the program is ready. It is based on:

- A `Board`, containing the `amount` of mines, the list of `fields` and the `width` and `height` of the map.
- A `Field`, containing the number of adjacent mines or a value indicating that the field is a mine itself. The `Field` also contains a `FieldState` (`Marked`, `Hidden` or `Shown`).

The game loop looks like the following:

```
play board = do
    -- Clear the screen
    putStrLn $ replicate 40 '\n'

    -- Show the board
    print board

    -- Get and process user input
    putStr "Command: "
    -- We are generating a new board to reflect the changes!
    newBoard <- parseInput board <$> getLine

    -- If the game is not ended, go to next step
    if gameEnded newBoard
    then return $ result newBoard
    else play newBoard
```

This works quite good right now, but I don't like the fact that after each turn I have to generate a new `Board`. It looks inefficient coming from an imperative language like C++, where you would just need to mutate the existing board.

To the point:

- Is this the correct way to do it?
- Will it be optimized by the compiler?

Comment: You might want to try out ST Monad (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19345615/917635).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right of course that completely replacing the board is less than optimal, however it's not necessarily as bad as you may think either. If `Board` uses a `[[FieldState]]`-2D-grid, then updating a single cell actually re-uses most of the rows (this works without thinking and is perfectly safe, *because* Haskell is purely functional): for an *n* × *n* grid the complexity is *O* (*n*), only a constant factor worse than what you need anyway for *looking up* any given field. It's definitely not going to be any problem whatsoever for a game like Minesweeper.

For something more performance-critical, there are dedicated array types that can do both lookup and updates of single fields (in the `IO` or `ST` monad) in *O* (1). For an application similar to yours, [`Data.Array.MArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html) is probably the best fit (though there's a certain trend in the community to rather write your abstractions right around the somewhat lower-level, more optimised [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) types).